# Bias and variance of a naive bayes classifier and KNN classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour

After reading the paper by J. Friedman, ”On bias, variance, 0/1-loss, and the curse-of-dimensionality,” Data Mining and Knowl- edge Discovery, 1997. I would like to estimate both bias and variance using cross-validation (or hold-out) using K-folds and the Iris dataset. In order to estimate the bias and variance of a simple multivariate normal (full covariance) class conditional model using the approach described in J. Friedman’s paper, I am comparing the bias and variance of KNN and Naive Bayes classifiers in python. I was wondering if anyone knows how to apply Friedman's formulas for bias and variance to these classifiers.
[image: Variance]
[image: Bias]